# Getting error NumberFormatException while using Integer.parseInt

Tags: java, android-studio

So I am writing this simple app to detect if a number is odd or even. I have defined a Button for detecting, a TextView and an EditText. The app is going to get text from the edittext and make it an int and then use the method to detect if it is odd or even. However, the app crashes at start and throws :

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(edttext.getText()).toString()"`

What should I do to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public TextView text1;
    public EditText edttext;
    public Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        edttext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttxt);
        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        String num = "(edttext.getText()).toString()";
        int a = Integer.valueOf(num);
       
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                findOddEven(a);
            }
        });
    }


    public void findOddEven(int num1) {
        if (num1%2==0) {

            text1.setText("Your Number Is Even!");

        }else {
            text1.setText("Your Number Is Odd!");
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: `String num = "(edttext.getText()).toString()";` Can't do this.  Strings aren't code and won't execute anything at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change

```
    String num = "(edttext.getText()).toString()";
```

To:

```
    String num = (edttext.getText()).toString();
```

The error perform since you try to cast the **text** (edttext.getText()).toString() to a number, and not its value.

**UPDATED**

Moving the following code into the onClick method, to get the data from the edittext while clicking.

Comment: Doing exactly as you said, still crashing

Comment: i think the data on the editText is not a number then, try to print the variable num right after this line.

Comment: Printed the variable, but it does not show up on console. Anything else that I print will be shown, but this one does not appear.

Comment: Are you sure that the ID of the editText is edttxt?

Comment: Yes, checked now.

Comment: Try to debug and see the value of num after this paticular line. It seems to me another issue that nothing are into edittext. Another approach: move all the code of the num and the casting into the onClick.

Comment: Alright did this sort of thing using toast message, and it showed empty meaning that there was nothing inserted in the edittext although I had already put a number. Btw I somehow fixed the crash by commenting those lines after the string num so I was able to do this toast thing.

Comment: Move all the code of the num and the casting into the onClick method. I think that should work, since the onCreate pops when there is nothing in the edittext, hence num is empty.. by calling this logic on click you will recieve the data while you clicked instead on creation.

Comment: Finally fixed by doing this. Thank you. Now it runs correctly without any crashes!

Comment: Im happy that solved the issue, already updated the answer. Please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public TextView text1;
    public EditText edttext;
    public Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        edttext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttxt);
        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        String num = edttext.getText().toString();
        Integer a=null;
        try{
              a = Integer.valueOf(num);
              btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      findOddEven(a);
                  }
              });
           }catch(NumberFormatException e){
             // write to log
           }
       
       
    }


    public void findOddEven(int num1) {
        if (num1%2==0) {

            text1.setText("Your Number Is Even!");

        }else {
            text1.setText("Your Number Is Odd!");
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this. App won't crash anymore but the button doesn't function anyway. Nothing happens when clicking on button.

Answer (score 0):

Like @markspace already said, your problem is on the assignment of num.
As you can check in the documentation of the String class ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)), a String is just an array of char, and when you do this assignment you are creating an array of strings with these characters, like ['(', 'e', 'd'...] or a string with this value "(edttext.getText())".

In order to solve this problem, you can just remove the double-quotes. Like this:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public TextView text1;
public EditText edttext;
public Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    edttext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttxt);
    btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    String num = edttext.getText().toString();
    int a = Integer.valueOf(num);
   
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            findOddEven(a);
        }
    });
}


public void findOddEven(int num1) {
    if (num1%2==0) {

        text1.setText("Your Number Is Even!");

    }else {
        text1.setText("Your Number Is Odd!");
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Doing exactly as you said, still crashing

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix this issue by using the suggestion from @Timor.
I copied everything about num variable and casting stuff inside the button onclick method. Now it works as it should!

Comment: Happy that everything works currectly!